# error CS0246, unity cannot find a namespace

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I will try to summarize my problem as best as i can but i am very new to using this program.

I want to reference to a gamemanager in unity so that i can use certain values that i created in a different script.
The full error is this:

Assets\FightingIdle.cs(8,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'GameManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FightingIdle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameManager GM;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void VechtKnop()
{
    GM.FightPoints += GM.FightDamage;
}
```

}

The problem occurs here: 'public GameManager GM;'

For some reason unity can't find the type/namespace. Anyone that can help me fix this?

Comment: If it can't find `GameManager`, then you have not *created an object and named it as such*. If you were doing that, you wouldn't be getting the error. You're getting the error because it can't identify the `GameManager` class you're trying to use. Where is `GameManager` defined (where is `public class GameManager' declared)?

Comment: Your class lacks a namespace.

Comment: Ken White 23, i just right clicked in the hierarchy and selected 'create empty', then i named it 'GameManager' is that not how you are supposed to do it?

Comment: CodeCaster what exactly is a namespace?

Comment: Please show us the first 17 lines of your `GameManager` file.

Comment: @RichardBatsbak you created a gameobject not a script

Comment: It is usually a good practice to learn C# before getting into unity

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your `GameManger.cs`
- Find the line that starts with `namespace <anything>`
- Copy that `<anything>`
- Add it to the top of your FightingIdle with `using <anything>`